# Problem getting text from website using selenium vba

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get some data from a website into Excel.... If I use View pagesource in Chrome it shows

```html
  <div class="buttons">
    <div class="vote" onclick="Vote.cast();" data-tooltip-text="Stem op deze foto">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="voteIcon">Stem op deze foto!</div>
        <div class="votes"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I inspect it, it shows

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <div class="vote voted" onclick="Vote.cast();" data-tooltip-text="Stem op deze foto">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="voteIcon">Stem op deze foto!</div>
        <div class="votes">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The number 2 (in this example) is the text I want to extract.... But whatever I try, it just returns an empty string.

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = detailbot.FindElementByClass("votes").text
```

Should do the trick in my opinion, but it doesn't

Comment: Can you share the url of the website?

Comment: @QHarr https://contest.myalbum.com/tvm/photo-vWqGwEKc1tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set MyBy = New By
While detailbot.IsElementPresent(MyBy.XPath("//div[text()='" & j & "']")) = False
    j = j + 1
Wend
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = j
```

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in the innerHTML/textContent properties. Try:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = detailbot.FindElementByClass("votes").Attribute("innerHTML")
```

or

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = detailbot.FindElementByClass("votes").Attribute("textContent")
```

[node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

> The textContent property of the Node interface represents the text
> content of the node and its descendants.

> textContent gets the content of all elements, including `<script>` and
> `<style>` elements. In contrast, innerText only shows “human-readable”
> elements.

> textContent returns every element in the node. In contrast, innerText
> is aware of styling and won’t return the text of “hidden” elements.

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with vba, but i found this issue: https://github.com/7Gabriel/selenium-vba/issues/126#issuecomment-210692163

Seems like `detailbot.findElementByClassName("votes").Text` should return a value.

Answer (score -1):

Get the Chrome extension RUTO XPath Finder. With Ruto you can click on an element, and obtain its Xpath.

```
debug.print CD.FindElementByXPath("").Text
debug.print CD.FindElementByXPath("").value
```

You can use this so the Ruto Extension shows up while running the ChromeDriver.

```
Private Const My_Extension As String = "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\ilcoelkkcokgeeijnopjnolmmighnppp\7.0.0_0" 'RUTO XPATH
cd.AddArgument "load-extension=" & My_Extension
```

You can use this to loop through all of the elements on the page. I added .ScrollIntoView, because on some pages the elements are not visible until they are in view. I added DoEvents to pause for a second incase the page needs to load, If the page loading is an issue, you could try to wait longer, or Do Until the element is present on the page. If .Text does not return a value, try .value

```
Dim ElemCounter As Long
Dim MyBy As By
Set MyBy = New By

ElemCounter = 2
Do Until CD.IsElementPresent(MyBy.XPath("//div[text()='" & ElemCounter & "']")) = False
    CD.FindElementByXPath("//div[text()='" & ElemCounter & "']").ScrollIntoView
    Debug.Print CD.FindElementByXPath("//div[text()='" & ElemCounter & "']").Text
    Debug.Print CD.FindElementByXPath("//div[text()='" & ElemCounter & "']").Value
    ElemCounter = ElemCounter + 1
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Comment: RUTO returns this Xpath: //div[text()='2'] but the "2" will change.... That's the value I want to read

Comment: Thank you Manon for the clarification. I edited the answer to loop through elements on the page. If the first element always starts with 2, then set ElemCounter = 2, else change ElemCounter = 1 or which ever the first element number on the page is.